# python numpy contains text "array"

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I am using a binarizer to get some one-hot-vectors.
For some reason my output arrays contain a text literally saying "array".

The form is like:

```
[array(
       [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
       ]
      )]
```

Comment: and what's the question?

Comment: it says "array" because it is a numpy array.

Comment: Question is how i can format the array in a better way.... especially to remove the "array ()"..guess it was answered by the next answer already. thanks

Answer (score 2):

It's not a string. It is a Numpy array inside of a list. Numpy arrays are formatted like that as an output.

Test it with 
    np.array([2,3]) 
The output will be 
    array([2, 3]).